# Java scanner for 2 character combinations

Tags: java

I have made a scanner in Java that displays how many letters there are in the input text, how many 'A' letters, 'B' letters, etc. But the real thing I need here is fir the scanner me to display how many "ch", "au", "iu" and other certain 2 letter combinations there are in this text. 
Since I am new to coding, I have no clue on how to do it.

Comment: Please provide some code for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the indexOf() method of the String class and know the number of occurrences. Just do a basic Google search.

Else, you can use third party libraries like apache commons and use the api like

StringUtils. countMatches()